Merge two GitHub repositories
I have a Spring Boot backend project and a React frontend project that I initialized with IntelliJ. I have been working on the 2 of them in 2 separate windows of IntelliJ each with their own git repositories. I want to combine the 2 into a large project with a folder structure like this:
BigProjectOnGithub
Git repository at base
--- Backend (has existing git repo with 200+ commits)
--- Frontend (has existing git repo with 200+ commits)

How do I merge the 2 so that a git log would should some existing commits from both projects so i can push this up to github, without the stupid references to other repos instead of just a folder?
mkdir bigproject; cd bigproject; git init; mkdir backend frontend; 

Copied all the contents of the Java Spring boot project and the React files over to the respective folders in the new repository.
Didn't work as I wanted.

What didn't work about it?  Are you getting an error with git or something else?

You could use git submodules but if you want to preserve both commit histories without rewriting, you need one repository for each of the projects. It's probably possible with rewriting history but that will have issues if there are other people working on it or if you have references to commit hashes.

The easiest way I would go is by merging, the two main branches into a single branch.
Something like this:
git init joined
cd joined
git remote add remote1 some-url
git remote add remote2 some-url
git fetch --all
git checkout -b branch1 remote1/main-branch-repo1
mkdir dir1
git mv * dir1 # move everything into dir1
git commit -m "moving everything into dir1"
git checkout -b branch2 remote2/main-branch-repo2
mkdir dir2
git mv * dir2
git commit -m "moving everything into dir2"
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories branch1 -m "joining together both projects"

Now rename the branch to something suitable and push where you feel like.
